# How do I get the first letter capitalized of two different textboxes?

Tags: powershell

How would I get the first letter capitalized of two different textboxes?
For example:

```
textbox1.text = 'john'
textbox2.text = 'doe'
```

When getting the first letter of both of those textboxes, it should show JD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is built into the `Get-Culture` cmdlet. There's a method named `.ToTitleCase()` that will allow you to capitalize things such as named.

```
(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($textbox1.text) + ' ' + (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($textbox2.text)
```

That would get you 'John Doe'. There is also a method `.ToUpper()` that will convert a character or string to entirely upper case, so you could get their initials, then run that through the `.ToUpper()` method to capitalize them.

```
$Initials = $textbox1.text[0] + $textbox2.text[0]
$Initials = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToUpper($Initials)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
($textbox1.text.substring(0,1)+$textbox1.text.substring(0,1)).toupper()
```

Comment: Thank you Wasif. This also helped me out.

Comment: I will run tests on both, but i feel this is much faster, because you're not calling more cmdlets, just some methods. But I may be wrong.

Comment: OK I tested this, and over 1 million iterations, the first answer (using get-culture) required over 20 seconds, where the substring required 5 seconds. Optimizations like these may not be the end all be all, but it's best to use the fastest option you can. Especially if the operation is repeated a lot.